# sharppcap: '.' characters instead of spaces with printHex() method

Tags: c#, wireshark, pcap, sharppcap

I am successfully parcing '.pcap' files using SharpPcap libary.

The goal is to retrieve XML data from the TCP/HTTP packets. In order to do this, I am using the code below (removed null checks to make it more readable):

```
Packet packet = Packet.ParsePacket(eventArguments.Packet.LinkLayerType, eventArguments.Packet.Data);
EthernetPacket ethernetPacket = ((EthernetPacket)packet);

IpPacket ipPacket = (IpPacket)packet.Extract(typeof(IpPacket));

TcpPacket tcpPacket = (TcpPacket)packet.Extract(typeof(TcpPacket));

string rawData = tcpPacket.PrintHex();
```

Moving, aside the hex values and the initial lines, I am able to extract the XML data from the **rawData** variable, along with an unexpected side-effect.

Instead of spaces, the `.PrintHex()` returns '.' characters:

Instead of:

```
<xml>Only text here</xml>
```

I am getting this:

```
<xml>Only.text.here</xml>
```

I am not doing any weird replacements or byte conversions. The above behavior is exactly what `.PrintHex()` returns.

- Is this by any chance the expected outcome?
- And more importantly... How can this be fixed or prevented? (having in mind that valid '.' from converted '.' cannot be distinguished)

---

Library versions:

- **.NET Framework**: > 4.5.2
- **Pcapsharp**: 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use override of `ToString()` method which seems to do exactly what you expect.

Optionally if that does not work, implement `public string PrintHex()` from `Packet` on your own. If you take a look at decompiled code here is your problem :

```
    if ((int) bytes[index - 1] < 33 || (int) bytes[index - 1] > 126)
      str2 += ".";
    else
      str2 += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[1]
      {
        bytes[index - 1]
      });
```

Only characters with `dec` code ranging from 33 to 126 will be left unchanged, rest will be replaced with `.` (including `space` which is 32 http://www.asciitable.com/). And since `BytesHighPerformance.Bytes` is public you can write your own extension method rather easily along those lines.

```
TcpPacket tcpPacket = (TcpPacket)packet.Extract(typeof(TcpPacket));
string rawData = tcpPacket.CustomPrintHex();

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string CustomPrintHex(this TcpPacket self)
    {
        byte[] bytes = self.BytesHighPerformance.Bytes;

        // copy / paste of `PrintHex()` with your custom conversion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. As a side note, ASCII codes 10 (new line) and 13 (carriage return) can be included, in order to keep the line separation within the content.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to others, so I am posting my final solution (which is based on the accepted answer).

Additional features:

- Utilizing string builder for performance
- Including new line characters

---

```
public class TcpPacketCustom: TcpPacket
{
    public static int AsciiRangeMin { get; } = 32;
    public static int AsciiRangeMax { get; } = 126;
    public static HashSet<int> AdditionalAsciiCodes { get; } = new HashSet<int> { 10, 13 }; //ascii codes of carriage and new line

    public TcpPacketCustom(ByteArraySegment byteArraySegment) : base(byteArraySegment) { }

    public new string PrintHex()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in this.BytesHighPerformance.Bytes)
        {
            int asciiCode = (int)b;
            if ( ((asciiCode < AsciiRangeMin) || (asciiCode > AsciiRangeMax)) && !AdditionalAsciiCodes.Contains(asciiCode) )
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(".");
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[1] { b }));
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

}
```